# How would i program analog to digital conversion using a microconroller in c

Tags: audio, signal-processing, microcontroller, digital

Im doing a dsp project and i want to take an anolog file and convert it to a digital output using a microconroller attached to a ADC on a dsp board. How would i program this in c?

Pretty much its as simple as that, atleast i think.

This is what i need.

Input --------- Output

Angolog --> Digital

Digital --> Anolog

Comment: I think you are underestimating the size of this project. However, you might get a better response in Electronics and Robotics. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You really need to clarify your question.  Like what do you mean by analog file?  File systems are binary from a programming perspective, sure the media is magnetic or other technologies and there is analog involved.    An ADC goes from Analog to Digital, so it is an an analog input not a digital output.

ADC analog to digital converter, takes analog inputs to the device and converts them to digital so you can use them inside the chip, program, save to files, etc.

DAC digital to analog converter, takes digital values and converts them to analog outputs.

In both cases you need to look at the specific details for the chips and the board.  From a programming perspective if nothing else you need to look into the details for the ADC and or DAC.  Microcontrollers having an ADC is not uncommon, but you need to read up on how to get the ADC on that microcontroller to initiate a sample, how to know when the sample has completed and how to read the digital data once the sample has been taken.  DACs are often external, sometimes serial, so you may have to bit bang spi or i2c or look into what hardware the microcontroller might have for speaking spi or i2c or if there is a dac in the microcontroller, how to use it (what registers to write, etc).

If you have a specific publicly available microcontroller board, for example an eval board, then that makes it much easier for folks here or elsewhere to show you where to look for the schematics, data sheets, etc.  Otherwise, even knowing exactly which microcontroller and what I/O pins are used, would be helpful when asking such a question.  There are probably lots of example programs out there that could be borrowed from.  And it could be as simple as a few lines of C to an existing library, or as complicated as many lines of C with interrupt service routines, and possibly some assembler.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely dependent on your hardware and there's no information in the question that would enable a real answer.

In general, you should see the documentation for your system, especially the AD/DA parts. There should be good examples. If there's a particular problem, post a more specific question.